# How do you Flip the screen like a coin transition in react native?

Tags: react-native, react-animations

I am trying to make the screen flip like a coin when button pressed on it. What I have done up-till now is I have successfully flipped two small screens, but it comes to a bit large screen the code is not working. Like here in my code two simple buttons are working fine, but when I call view from other big screen, the view doesn't show up. I think it is because the view that will is flipped becomes invisible but remains on its place and other view can't be placed on that space, so when it comes to larger screen the whole thing doesn't show up.  I am new to RN. Help.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {
  AppRegistry,
  StyleSheet,
  Text,
  View,
  TouchableOpacity,
  Animated
} from 'react-native';
var screenWidth = require('Dimensions').get('window').width;
export default class animatedbasic extends Component {
  componentWillMount() {
    this.animatedValue = new Animated.Value(0);
    this.value = 0;
    this.animatedValue.addListener(({ value }) => {
      this.value = value;
    })
    this.frontInterpolate = this.animatedValue.interpolate({
      inputRange: [0, 180],
      outputRange: ['0deg', '180deg'],
    })
    this.backInterpolate = this.animatedValue.interpolate({
      inputRange: [0, 180],
      outputRange: ['180deg', '360deg']
    })
    this.frontOpacity = this.animatedValue.interpolate({
      inputRange: [89, 90],
      outputRange: [1, 0]
    })
    this.backOpacity = this.animatedValue.interpolate({
      inputRange: [89, 90],
      outputRange: [0, 1]
    })
  }

  flipCard() {
    if (this.value >= 90) {
      Animated.spring(this.animatedValue,{
        toValue: 0,
        friction: 8,
        tension: 10
      }).start();
    } else {
      Animated.spring(this.animatedValue,{
        toValue: 180,
        friction: 8,
        tension: 10
      }).start();
    }

  }

  render() {
    const frontAnimatedStyle = {
      transform: [
        { rotateY: this.frontInterpolate }
      ]
    }
    const backAnimatedStyle = {
      transform: [
        { rotateY: this.backInterpolate }
      ]
    }

    return (
      <View style={{ flex:1, justifyContent:'center', alignItems:'center'}} >
        <View >
          <Animated.View style={[styles.flipCard, frontAnimatedStyle, {opacity: this.frontOpacity}]}>

          </Animated.View>
          <Animated.View style={[styles.flipCard, styles.flipCardBack, backAnimatedStyle, {opacity: this.backOpacity}]}>
          <View>
             <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => this.flipCard()} style={{ width:(screenWidth/2), height:70, backgroundColor:'black'}}>
 <Text style={{color:'white', fontSize:22, fontWeight:'bold'}}>  I am on Back</Text>
                </TouchableOpacity>
             </View>
          </Animated.View>
        </View>

      </View>
    );
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({

  flipCard: {

    backfaceVisibility: 'hidden',
  },
  flipCardBack: {

    top: 0,
  },

});
```

I have also tried **react-native-card-flip**

**Flipping.js**

```
  render() {
        return (
          <CardFlip style={styles.cardContainer} ref={(card) => this.card 
            =card}>
          <FronEnd />
          <Backend />
        </CardFlip> }
```

**FronEnd.js**

```
 render()
    {
        return (
            <View>
                 <CardFlip style={styles.cardContainer} ref={(card) => this.card = card} >
            ....................................................
   <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => this.card.flip()}
</TouchableOpacity >
               </CardFlip>
            </View>
        );
    }
}
```

**Backend.js**

```
 render()
    {
        return (
            <View>
                <CardFlip style={styles.cardContainer} ref={(card) => this.card = card} >
            .......................
<TouchableOpacity onPress={() => this.card.flip()}
</TouchableOpacity >
               </CardFlip>
            </View>
        );
    }
```

Comment: so you wanted nested card flipping ?

Comment: yes, it is so...

Comment: where are you using flipping.js component ?

Comment: In a navigator. First Screen.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a npm module for this :

**Installation :**

```
npm install --save react-native-card-flip
```

**Usage :**

```
import CardFlip from 'react-native-card-flip';


  <CardFlip style={styles.cardContainer} ref={(card) => this.card = card} >
    <TouchableOpacity style={styles.card} onPress={() => this.card.flip()} ><Text>AB</Text></TouchableOpacity>
    <TouchableOpacity style={styles.card} onPress={() => this.card.flip()} ><Text>CD</Text></TouchableOpacity>
  </CardFlip>
```

See [Output](https://github.com/lhandel/react-native-card-flip/blob/master/screenshots/animation2.gif)

Npm module : [Github](https://github.com/lhandel/react-native-card-flip#readme)

Comment: I am facing issues with the `height of the card which is static in styles` so how can we make dynamic?